# ParseQuery.count() Not Firing on Parse Relation Query Object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I am rather frustrated at this point trying to figure out why I can't count the amount of objects or even return any objects that are assigned to a `ParseRelation` column.

This is my code for attempting to count the rows in a `ParseRelation`:

```
var stats = myObject.get("stats");

var likeRelation  = stats.relation("likeRelation");

var likesQuery = likeRelation.query();
            
likesQuery.count().then(function(count){           

 console.log(count);

});
```

All of the variables (`myObject`, `stats`, `likeRelation`, `likesQuery`) have been verified to be as expected meaning they are valid objects - the only thing that doesn't work in these few lines of code is the call to `likesQuery.count()`.

So as a workaround I tried just returning all of the objects in the `likeRelation` using `find()` but that is seemingly ignored just like the call to `count()`.

Am I doing something wrong?  I can't figure out why this won't fire.  I have no problem calling `.add()` or `.remove()` on the `ParseRelation` (I have verified that the 'likeRelation` table are getting populated with my data - I just can't do anything with the data).

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Per request here is my `stats` object.  I have verified that all of the objects are valid objects just like this one.

```
{'createdAt': '2015-11-16T18:16:42.072Z',
 'likeRelation': {'__type': 'Relation', 'className': '_User'},
 'objectId': 'PW0bI77H0h',
 ‘data’: {'__type': 'Pointer',
                 'className': ‘Data’,
                 'objectId': '0Ce9i5Yi19’},
 'participantRelation': {'__type': 'Relation', 'className': '_User'},
 'total_likes': 0,
 'updatedAt': '2015-11-16T18:16:42.072Z'}
```

Again I don't have any issues working with this ParseRelation (meaning I can `.add()` and `.remove()` from it just fine) it just seems to be a bug in Parse that doesn't allow queries to be executed on ParseRelations or something along those lines.

Comment: Could you double check your assertion that `stats` is a valid object?  Maybe post the result of JSON.stringify(stats).  Best guess given the symptoms is that stats is an un-fetched pointer.

Comment: @danh - I updated my question with the `stats` object. All of the objects are valid just like this one.  In fact I can even call `.add()` and `.remove()` on the relation object - I just can't execute queries for some reason.

Comment: Yep, that looks like a good object.  Next idea is read restriction (either at class level or ACLs on user).  If you were preventing reads, that would explain it.